# Connecting Flutter with Websocket Spring Security STOMP

Tags: flutter, spring-boot, spring-security, stomp, spring-websocket

I've been struggling for days trying to find a guide or something to connect my flutter app to the Websocket in my backend. It's all new to me... Nothing happens in the console of my backend but I keep getting this message in the console of my flutter app:

```
I/flutter ( 9912): A Web socket error occurred in web socket connection :: Invalid argument(s): The url has to start with http/https
I/flutter ( 9912): A debug error occurred in web socket connection :: Unknown connection error...reconnecting
```

This is the controller in my flutter app

```html
 void connect() {
    try {
      _stompClient = StompClient(
        config: StompConfig.sockJS(
          url: "ws://10.0.2.2:8080/ws",
          stompConnectHeaders: {
            'Authorization':
                'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1c2VyMSIsImlhdCI6MTY5NTE3NjcwMiwiZXhwIjoxNjk1MTc4MTQyfQ.iD_IB6zf80o7zgB4_rMbfI0tOeza1CgWRKz3mtUQQwmHYfTZopXO3qMRHpeCi_DzQjLjtsFB0Shq8zyir8ttqA', // please note <<<<<
          },
          onStompError: (StompFrame frame) {
            print(
                'A stomp error occurred in web socket connection :: ${frame.body}');
          },
          onWebSocketError: (dynamic frame) {
            print(
                'A Web socket error occurred in web socket connection :: ${frame.toString()}');
          },
          onDebugMessage: (dynamic frame) {
            print(
                'A debug error occurred in web socket connection :: ${frame.toString()}');
          },
          onConnect: (StompFrame connectFrame) {
            print('Connected with the following frames ${connectFrame.body}');
            // Now you can access _stompClient here
            print('StompClient: $_stompClient');

            Map<String, String> asdf = {};
            var clientUnSubscribeFn = _stompClient!.subscribe(
              destination: "ws://10.0.2.2:8080/user/queue/newMember",
              headers: asdf,
              callback: (frame) {
                // Received a frame for this subscription
                print("here" + frame.body!);
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      );

      _stompClient!.activate();
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }

  sendClientMessage(String msg) async {
    Map<String, String> asdf = {};
    var clientUnSubscribeFn = await _stompClient!.subscribe(
      destination: "ws://10.0.2.2:8080/topic/public/newMember",
      headers: asdf,
      callback: (frame) {
        // Received a frame for this subscription
        print("here" + frame.body!);
      },
    );
    _stompClient!.send(
      destination: "ws://10.0.2.2:8080/app/register",
      body: "newUser\n",
      headers: asdf,
    );
    clientUnSubscribeFn = await _stompClient!.subscribe(
      destination: "ws://10.0.2.2:8080/user/newUser/msg",
      headers: asdf,
      callback: (frame) {
        // Received a frame for this subscription
        print("here" + frame.body!);
      },
    );
  }
```

And in my back I have this config

```java
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
    public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

        @Override
        public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
            registry.addEndpoint("/ws").setAllowedOrigins("*");
            registry.addEndpoint("/ws").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
        }

        @Override
        public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
            registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
            registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        }
```

and this controller

```java
    package com.backend.api.controllers;


    import com.backend.api.websocket.ChatMessage;
    import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.MessageMapping;
    import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.Payload;
    import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.SendTo;
    import org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessageHeaderAccessor;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

    @Controller
    public class ChatController {

        @MessageMapping("/chat.sendMessage")
        @SendTo("/topic/public")
        public ChatMessage sendMessage(
                @Payload ChatMessage chatMessage
        ) {
            return chatMessage;
        }

        @MessageMapping("/chat.addUser")
        @SendTo("/topic/public")
        public ChatMessage addUser(
                @Payload ChatMessage chatMessage,
                SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headerAccessor
        ) {
            // Add username in web socket session
            headerAccessor.getSessionAttributes().put("username", chatMessage.getSender());
            return chatMessage;
        }


    }
```